# kotlin Android spinner notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, dynamic, kotlin, spinner

I would like to update spinner2 dynamically, so i use the function notifyDataSetChanged(). However it doesn't work, please kindly help.

Here with the code. the array content of spinner2 changed, after the spinner1 selected. Then it suppose to update spinner2 dynamically, but it didn't.

```
     spinnerOne = findViewById(R.id.spinner1) as Spinner
        spinnerTwo = findViewById(R.id.spinner2) as Spinner

        //result = findViewById(R.id.tv_result) as TextView

        val options = arrayOf("111", "222", "333", "222", "333", "222", "333", "222", "333", "222", "333", "222", "333", "222", "333", "222", "333", "222", "333", "222", "333", "222", "333", "222", "333")
        val taiwan = arrayOf("xxx","yyy","zzz")
        var tempArray = options

        //spinnerOne.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item,options)
        spinnerOne.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, options)

        var dataAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  R.layout.item, tempArray)

        spinnerTwo.setAdapter(dataAdapter)
//        dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()



        spinnerOne.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                //TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.


            }

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                //TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.

                tempArray = taiwan
                for (element in tempArray) {
                    println(element)
                }
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }




        spinnerTwo.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                //TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.

            }

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                //TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.


                //result.text = options.get(position)
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: You don't call `notifyDataSetChanged` after spinner click, you made it only in initialization. Add it into `onItemSelected`.

Comment: I put dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() into onItemSelected of spinner1, It still didn't change the content of spinner2. Is anything I did wrong?

Comment: Update your code to see changes.

Comment: code has been updated

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing adapters content - you are just set new variable `tempArray` value. After `tempArray = taiwan` call adapter still holds data equivalent to `options` variable.

**Edited**

Sorry for the first code example - I didn't know that `ArrayAdapter` doesn't support content changing. I have never edited it for myself. :) I often use custom adapters - it could be solution for you too.

Better to make `tempArray` variable with [`MutableList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html) type. Then change content of it.

```
tempArray.clear()
tempArray.addAll(taiwan)
```

This code changes collection content that referenced by adapter, so adapter can see it. In your code is just switching references in variable.

And don't forget about `notifyDataSetChanged` after all.

Comment: how to call notifyDataSetChanged in ViewModel?

Comment: As adapter is known to be view level entity, you can't directly invoke its methods. So you need some observable event, that should be raised in ViewModel. Then subscribe your view level (in general it's `Activity`) where adapter is for this event and call `notifyDataSetChanged` in this observer.

Answer (score 0):

i provide one simple java code method for spinner city and region when spinner city value selected based on region value set. you can set remove perform any operation.

```
   private void setSpinser() {
    spCity = findViewById(R.id.city);
    spRegion = findViewById(R.id.reigon);
    List<String> cityName = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<String> regionName = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> regionAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    cityName.add("Select city");
    cityName.add("Ahmadabad");
    cityName.add("Surat");
    cityName.add("Delhi");
    ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DbInsert.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cityName);
    spCity.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
    spCity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            switch (spCity.getSelectedItem().toString())
            {
                case "Ahmadabad":
                    regionName.add("Abc");
                    regionName.add("cde");
                    regionName.add("efg");
                    regionAdapter.addAll(regionName);
                    spRegion.setAdapter(regionAdapter);
                    regionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case "Surat":
                    regionName.add("pqr");
                    regionName.add("stu");
                    regionName.add("xyz");
                    regionAdapter.addAll(regionName);
                    spRegion.setAdapter(regionAdapter);
                    regionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```